# How to handle state in compose if you have TextFields in LazyColumn?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, android-compose-textfield

I've a list of QA(String,String) where each list item represents 2 TextFields in Lazycolumn, I tried several things but my TextFields value is not updating.

I tried mutableStateListOf() , mutableStateOf() ,

I'm passing the QA(String) value to the TextField and updating the value by catching event in viewModel.

```
     LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(
            uiState.questionAnswers
        ) { index, item ->
            QuestionAnswerCard(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 16.dp),
                question =item.questing,
                ans = item.answer,
                onQuestionValueChange = { value ->
                    viewModel.onEvent(
                        CreateFlashCardScreenEvents.OnChangeQuestion(
                            value,
                            index
                        )
                    )
                },
                onAnswerValueChange = {
                    viewModel.onEvent(CreateFlashCardScreenEvents.OnChangeAnswer(it, index))
                }
            )
        }
    }


@Composable
fun QuestionAnswerCard(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    question: String,
    ans: String,
    onQuestionValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onAnswerValueChange: (String) -> Unit
) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
        elevation = 6.dp
    ) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            TextField(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                value = question,
                onValueChange = onQuestionValueChange
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
            TextField(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                value = ans,
                onValueChange = onAnswerValueChange
            )
        }
    }
}

class CreateFlashCardsViewModel : ViewModel() {
var createFlashCardUiState by mutableStateOf(CreateFlashCardUiState())
    private set

var stateList = mutableStateListOf<QuestionAnswer>()

init {
    createFlashCardUiState = createFlashCardUiState.copy(
        questionAnswers = createInitialEmptyQAList()
    )
    stateList.addAll(createInitialEmptyQAList())
}
private fun addNewQAinList() {
    val qAList = createFlashCardUiState.questionAnswers + QuestionAnswer(
        createFlashCardUiState.questionAnswers.size.toString(),
        ""
    )
    createFlashCardUiState = createFlashCardUiState.copy(questionAnswers = qAList)
    stateList = stateList.apply {
        add(QuestionAnswer())
    }
}

private fun createInitialEmptyQAList(): MutableList<QuestionAnswer> {
    return mutableListOf(
        QuestionAnswer(
            questing = "Test Q",
            answer = "Test A"
        ),
        QuestionAnswer(
            questing = "Test !",
            answer = "Test !"
        )
    )
}

/*In ViewModel*/
fun onEvent(event: CreateFlashCardScreenEvents) {
    when (event) {
        is CreateFlashCardScreenEvents.OnChangeQuestion -> {
            createFlashCardUiState = createFlashCardUiState.copy(
                questionAnswers = createFlashCardUiState.questionAnswers.apply {
                    get(event.index).questing = event.value
                }
            )
            /*tried different state */
            stateList.get(event.index).questing = event.value

        }
```

[image]

[image]

[image: I think this is where I'm making mistake]

Comment: Can you post your code? I can't debug from the picture

Comment: Can you show a stripped down version of your ViewModel? showing the related codes to your concern?

Comment: Hey @z.y I've updated the code snippet, I've used two different states just to try different things but none of them worked

Comment: There's a lot of compile error, can't run your code to see the issue.